P4V can't submit file to NAS: "mkdir: //nas/p4v/: The user name or password is incorrect", credentials ok in windows
P4V is stuggling to submit files to my depot on my nas, error:
2 errors reported
mkdir: //nas/p4v/: The user name or password is incorrect.
Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 1'.
Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
Now windows have credentials for the drive and I can use it perfectly, the drive is always available.
What can I do?
I tried to mess around with sending a password to the depot itself like //nas/p4v/... user/password
And many other configurations but p4Admin doesn't like anything past the ... I don't think.
